# Tag Parsing JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

i'm working on a tag parser to create a sort of html-like markup. I'm using RegExp to achieve this, as it deals with strings being sent through the server. The issue i'm having with this is utilizing multiple instances of the same tag in a line. Matching like this:

```
 "<item>a</item><item>b</item>".match(/\<item\>(.*)(\<\/\>|\<\/item\>)/gi)
```

The issue here is that the string i executed the match on returns as one match, 
I need each

```
 <item>...</item> or <item>...</>
```

instance to be in a separate match. How can I make this happen?

Comment: obligatory: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Try `.*?` instead of `.*`. Anyway, why not use an existing XML parser?

Comment: Kind of an aside: why are you escaping the `<` and `>` characters?

Comment: Because it isn't xml, because it isn't html, and because I don't know any better. If not assumed, I'm not that great with RegExp (yet).

Comment: you can do xml and html with RegExp just fine, _EXCEPT_ when it has nested repetitive tag names. ex `<div><div>`, and it sounds like that limitiation may be an issue for your syntax as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *[lazy quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)* (`.*?`) to match tags separately

```
<item>(.*?)(<\/>|</item>)
```

**JavaScript**

```js
var tag = '<item>a</item><item>b</item><item>c</>';
var result = tag.match(/<item>(.*?)(<\/>|<\/item>)/ig);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Plus one million for constructive help. :-) Thank you.